# Error occurred within 'ARCHITECTURE' When trying to compile VHDL code

Tags: vhdl

I am trying to write code for a state machine with 3 states (+a forth initial state that is nver reached after the it is left, which is in the second clock pulse). The state machine's output is connected to thre LED's, if direction is true, then the LED's should light up in this order 100>010>001 (In a loop), if direction is the LED's should light up in this order 001>010>100. When the machine first starts it doesn't matter which LED lights up, in my case I choose none (000).
The problem is that when I try to compile the code I get the following rather cryptic (At least for a beginner like myself) error message:

```
 Error occurred within 'ARCHITECTURE' at line 14, column 28 in IC.vhd.
```

Line 86 is marked in the code. And here is the full output:

```
Compiling 'IC.vhd' in 'C:\VHDL\MyProjects'.
VHDL parser (vhdlfe V6.3 IR 35)
Library 'work' => directory 'lc22v10'
Linking 'C:\Program Files\Cypress\Warp\bin\std.vhd'.
Linking 'C:\Program Files\Cypress\Warp\lib\common\cypress.vhd'.
Linking 'C:\Program Files\Cypress\Warp\lib\common\work\cypress.vif'.
Library 'ieee' => directory 'C:\Program Files\Cypress\Warp\lib\ieee\work'
Linking 'C:\Program Files\Cypress\Warp\lib\ieee\work\stdlogic.vif'.
IC.vhd (line 86, col 8):  (E0) syntax error
Error occurred within 'ARCHITECTURE' at line 14, column 28 in IC.vhd.
```

Here is my code:

```
library IEEE;

use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;

entity ic is
    port(clk, direction:in std_logic; output:out std_logic_vector(2 dowton 0));
end ic;

architecture Moore of ic is
    type latches_state is (st0,st1,st2,st3);
    signal state:latches_state;
        begin
            next_state:process(clk)
                begin
                    if rising_edge(clk) then
                       case state is
                           when st0=>
                              if direction='1' then
                                  state<=st1;
                              else
                                  state<=st3;
                            end if;

                        when st1=>
                          if direction='1' then
                              state<=st2;
                        else
                             state<=st3;
                        end if;

                    when st2=>
                          if direction='1' then
                              state<=st3;
                          else
                              state<=st1;
                         end if;

                    when st3=>
                          if direction='1' then
                              state<=st1;
                          else
                              state<=st2;
                          end if;
            end case;
        end if;
    end process next_state;

    output-proc:process(state)//This is line 86 (This comment does not exist in the original code I am trying to compile)
    begin
        if state=st0 then output<="000";
        elsif state=st1 then output<="001";
        elsif state=st2 then output<="010";
        elsif state=st3 then output<="100";
        end if;
    end process output-pro;
end Moore;
```

Comment: process identifier `output-proc` is not allowed.   Legal VHDL identifiers must begin with a letter and can contain only letters, digits, and non-consecutive underscore (_) characters. `output_proc` . same goes for `end process output-pro` . And if you are using a comment, use VHDL comment `--`. not `//`

Comment: Also the reserved word `downto` is misspelled in the port declaration.

Comment: Thanks a lot man that really helped. Downto is misspelled only here but not in the original code. The problem was "-"  in output-proc  like you mentioned, the code compiled succesfully after replacing it with "_".

Comment: You could have also made it an extended identifier \output-proc\.  '-' is a graphic character.